# Painting to both a JFrame and a jpeg using java

Tags: java, jframe, bufferedimage

So, I have hit something of a wall. I am trying to grab a JFrame's contents or the JFrame as a whole convert it to or draw it into a BufferedImage and then write that image to a jpeg file. I got the write to file bit to work all right. The trouble is I can't find a method that lets me get the content of the JFrame without some weird issues.

I tried using a Robot but that came with a load of issues like causing the program to hang and alpha layers not working right.

The method that I found which seemed to show the most promise isn't working any better. It doesn't cause my program to hang but unfortunately when I get the contents of the JFrame using this method the resulting image is the same size as the JFrame but contains nothing but a grey panel with a black boarder 25 pixels at the top and a 3 pixel on all other sides. this corresponds to the boarder size of the JFrame itself.

I am wondering if perhaps it is to do with the BufferStrategy. or maybe I am only getting the back pane of the JFrame in which case I need to know how to grab the front or the whole thing. But really I have no idea where to go with this and most of the result I get from searching are about putting an image into a JFrame rather than turning a JFrame into an image.

I have cut down the files I wrote as much as I can and will post there here.

**This now works, with a few odd eccentricities lingering from it's numerous revisions**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BufferStrategy graphicBuffer;
    int frame = 0;

    public static void main(String[] cats) {
        new Window("Testing", 600, 400);
    }

    public Window(String title, int sizeX, int sizeY) {
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(sizeX, sizeY);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setUndecorated(false);
        this.setVisible(true);

        System.out.print("New Input: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.nextLine();
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            input = scanner.next();
            if (input.equals("end")) {
                scanner.close();
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Working " + input);
                render();
                System.out.print("New Input: ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("End of Loop");
    }

    public void render(boolean toImg)
    {
        if( toImg ){
            renderToImage();
        } else {
            renderToScreen();
        }
    }

    public void render() {
        if (graphicBuffer == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            graphicBuffer = getBufferStrategy();
        }
        Graphics g = graphicBuffer.getDrawGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Rectangle bounds = g2.getDeviceConfiguration().getBounds();
        int h = (int) bounds.getHeight();
        int w = (int) bounds.getWidth();

        Insets insets = this.getInsets();
        int t = insets.top;
        int l = insets.right;
        int r = insets.left;
        int b = insets.bottom;

        int areaW = w - (l + r);
        int areaH = h - (t + b);

        g2.setColor(new Color(100, 0, 0));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

        flicker(g2, l, t, areaW, areaH);

        g2.dispose();
        g.dispose();
        graphicBuffer.show();

        grabFrame();
    }

    public void renderToImage( ) 
    {
        frame++;
        if (graphicBuffer == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            graphicBuffer = getBufferStrategy();
        }

        Rectangle bounds = this.getBounds();
        int h = (int) bounds.getHeight();
        int w = (int) bounds.getWidth();

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage( this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Insets insets = this.getInsets();
        int t = insets.top;
        int l = insets.right;
        int r = insets.left;
        int b = insets.bottom;

        int areaW = w - (l + r);
        int areaH = h - (t + b);

        g2.setColor(new Color(100, 0, 0));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

        flicker(g2, l, t, areaW, areaH);

        g2.dispose();
        g.dispose();
        g = graphicBuffer.getDrawGraphics();
        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage( image, 0, 0, null );
        g2.dispose();
        g.dispose();
        graphicBuffer.show();

        testPrintToJpeg( image, frame );
    }

    public void testPrintToJpeg(BufferedImage frame, int frNum) {
        try {
            String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
            File outputFile = new File(userHome + "/Desktop/JavaOutput/EOL" + frNum + ".jpg");

            if (outputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
                System.out.println("[FrameToFile] Missing Folders Probably Added");
            }

            IIOImage outputImage = new IIOImage(frame, null, null);

            ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();
            writer.setOutput(new FileImageOutputStream(outputFile));
            ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
            writeParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            writeParam.setCompressionQuality(1.0f);
            writer.write(null, outputImage, writeParam);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Fail at Image Writer");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I can work out what the problem relates to I will figure out what the best title for this problem is. But right now all I know for sure is JFrame.paint(BufferedImage.getGraphics()) results in a grey image regardless of the contents of the JFrame. and what endless fun! Something in my quick and dirty workaround can result in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In grabFrame you're calling the paint method of the content pane component to ask it to paint itself into the image's graphics context. But there's nothing on the content pane, which is a separate component. Your render method ignores the content pane and paints to the frame directly.

The second problem is that, even if you called the frame's paint method instead, the paint method ignores the supplied graphics context and paints into the buffer strategy instead. The image neither knows nor cares that this has happened. The buffer strategy for the frame is unrelated to the image.

To draw to the image, you'll have to use the graphics context of the image instead of the one from the buffer strategy.

Comment: Thanks. that is good to know. Any suggested reading? I have no idea what the context of the image is if not the frame it was drawn into so I need a hint on where to start looking.

Comment: Sorry, by graphics context I simply mean the `Graphics` object. The graphics object of the image draws on to the image. The graphics object from the buffer strategy draws on to the frame. To draw on to the image, you must use the graphics object returned by the call to `image.getGraphics()` in your render method. All you need to do is move the painting code that is in render() into some method that takes a graphics object as a parameter. Then, you can call that method either with the graphics object from the buffer strategy, or the graphics object for the image, as needed.

Comment: Ouh? I shall go give that a try post haste! thank you!

Comment: Ahh spoot. that will result in Render having to run twice wont it. once for the JFrame and again for the jpeg. I supose I could just ditch the BufferStrategy and paint into a BufferedImage then push that onto the frame before passing it to the jpeg saver. I was hoping there was a way to grab the finished product after it had been painted into the frame to save on work load.

Comment: Yeah, studying your code again, I'm not sure I've given you the best advice. I'm extremely confused by which of your methods are supposed to be calling each other. The calling hierarchy is almost circular. Is your primary intention to store these frames to JPEGs, or to render frames to the screen, or do you always do both for every frame?

Comment: Yeah I think this hacked down version of my scripts is a poor example. I think I have in fact introduced an odd infinite loop by overriding the paint method. But yes. The way it is now every single frame should be painted to the Jframe and saved as a jpeg. Which in the case of this particular script here would just result in a small square moving about randomly. But in the full version it should show a a large tile based map to the left, a small stylized map in the to[ right, shifting clouds in the background, and information about the area being show in the bottom right.

Comment: If the JPEGs are vital rather than diagnostic output then extracting them from the frame is certainly the wrong approach because it ties up the rendering code in the GUI in an untidy way. It may also place you at the mercy of OS-specific display quirks, such as the saved image being limited by the color depth of the screen (potentially even black & white), or not being rendered at all if the screensaver starts up. When JPEG output is needed, you should create the BufferedImage at the start of rendering and render only into that, drawing the BufferedImage to the frame when ready.

Comment: Great. I'll keep my current render code as is and store it somewhere safe then implement the alternative as you suggested. Knowing why something doesn't work is every bit as helpful to me as knowing how to do it. Thank you very much for your time and effort!